# Regular expression for validating SQL Server table name

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am creating dynamic SQL Server table using C# code but I need to validate the table name.

What is a regular expression for validating SQL Server table names?

Comment: Whats wrong with `\w`? i.e.. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ??

Comment: I am referring this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign

Comment: Whats about this Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\[\]. -_0123456789]{1,128}$");
if (!regex.IsMatch(tableName)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid table name");

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The regex described in the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign) should be:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[\p{L}_][\p{L}\p{N}@$#_]{0,127}$");
```

Note that in general you'll have to embed the name of the table in `[...]`, because of the rule 3 (so `SELECT * FROM [SET]` is a valid query, because, while `SET` is a reserved keyword, you can "escape" it with the `[...]`)

Note that in the linked page the rule is incomplete:

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

3. The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words. When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, **the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets**. The words that are reserved depend on the database compatibility level. This level can be set by using the ALTER DATABASE statement.

And they forgot: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

> Is the name of the new table. Table names must follow the rules for identifiers. **table_name can be a maximum of 128 characters**, except for local temporary table names (names prefixed with a single number sign (#)) that cannot exceed 116 characters.

The rule that I've written is for "full" tables, not for temporary tables, and doesn't include schema name.

Comment: Even if it is not recommended the first character can be `@` or `#`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I trusted https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx: *A regular identifier that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object. An identifier that starts with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure.* I'm excluding temporary tables, so no `#`, and for the `@` sign it seems to be forbidden.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte But at least on the SQLFiddle and on the SQL Express LocalDB that I have here (sorry, no full SQL Server on my machine), it seems that `[@Foo]` and `[Foo Bar]` are both valid table names... so it seems that the rules given on MSDN are "de minimis" rules, and other names are valid.

Comment: I think it is only warnings about these particular cases, from the same page: *Although the number sign or double number sign characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects, we do not recommend this practice. [...] Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with @@.* . The number sign is indeed reserved for temp tables.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte My problem is that the name of the tables seems to be more a "anything goes"... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af4ca/2 I was able to name a table `° § ^ ? * - %`

Comment: Incredible, and it works too with a beaver table: `[(8B °)<##)]`

Comment: SqlFiddle was playing games on me, so I tried with another sandbox site, [rextester](http://rextester.com/EOWLV77113) and adding more special chars: `° § ^ ? * - % + / \ "`. That still seems to work... **Edit** and it works on a recent LocalDb as well

Comment: You got it wrong. The first char may include `_@#`.

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler The `_` is included (`[\p{L}_]`), while the `@` and the `#` would make the table a table variable/a temporary table, but as I've said in the response _The rule that I've written is for "full" tables, not for temporary tables, and doesn't include schema name._

Comment: Just a note, this RegEx is made by a rule, which is more like a recommendation, and does not allow table name to start with a number, which is allowed and is being used in some cases.