# Regex for validating table name in SQL Server (database compatibility level 120)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex

I am trying to validate the table/column name using [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30152027/3747770), but it's not working.

For `ValidateTableName("18_18_mapped")`, it returns `false`. But for `ValidateTableName("mappingStorage_f9dc07dbca414e2d86db00114a9104a3")` - it returns `true`.

Any input on validating the table/column name would be helpful.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool temp = ValidateTableName("18_18_mapped"); // Returns false
    ...
}

private static bool ValidateTableName(string tableName)
{
    string regexForTableName = @"^[\p{L}_][\p{L}\p{N}@$#_]{0,127}$";
    return Regex.IsMatch("[" + tableName + "]", regexForTableName);
}
```

Comment: You can define "not working"?

Comment: for ValidateTableName("18_18_mapped"), it returns false. But for ValidateTableName("mappingStorage_f9dc07dbca414e2d86db00114a9104a3"); returns true

Comment: Have you tried to use different pattern, such as: `\d+_\d+_mapped`?

Comment: You do not use the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151800/regular-expression-for-validating-sql-server-table-name/30152027#30152027 correctly.  You add square brackets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not add the square brackets:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(tableName, regexForTableName);
```

The brackets in the pattern are necessary to denote a character class. These are not literal square brackets.

Also, I'd declare/compile the regex outside the method for better efficiency:

```
private static readonly Regex regexForTableName = new Regex(@"^[\p{L}_][\p{L}\p{N}@$#_]{0,127}$");

private static bool ValidateTableName(string tableName)
{
    return regexForTableName.IsMatch(tableName);
}
```

**EDIT**:

According to MSDN, these are the [specifications for database identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx). I cannot find any specs stating that the first character can be a digit. However, if you need to allow it, add the `\p{N}` pattern:

```
^(?:[\p{N}\p{L}_][\p{L}\p{N}@$#_]{0,127}|\[.{1,126}\])$
```

I am adding `\[.{1,126}\]` to support all the names that are enclosed into `[]`, and they must be 128 characters long. The regex matches only non-temporary table names.

Comment: for ValidateTableName("18_18_mapped"), it returns false even if I remove the brackets. But for ValidateTableName("mappingStorage_f9dc07dbca414e2d86db00114a9104a3"); returns true

Comment: `18_18_mapped` starts with a digit and does not meet the regex pattern. Why do you expect it to be true?

Comment: but 18_18_mapped is a valid sql table name.

Comment: So, it seems you have database compatibility level set to other than 100 value. What is it set to in your case?

Comment: database compatibility level is at 120

Comment: second part of expression should be \\[.{1,128}\\]  this is because square sql server will use the outer most square brackets as an escape sequence so you can have 128 characters between the outermost square brackets

Comment: @NJMR I just tested running `CREATE TABLE 18_18_mapped (Foo int)` at compatibility 120 and it fails. Did you mean `[18_18_mapped]`?