# Retrieve stored procedure name from string

Tags: c#, string

This stored procedure is in a string variable and I want to retrieve the name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetEmployeesTest2   
    @LastName nvarchar(50),   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)   
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    SELECT 
        FirstName, LastName, Department  
    FROM 
        HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory  
    WHERE 
        FirstName = @FirstName 
        AND LastName = @LastName  
        AND EndDate IS NULL;  
GO
```

I would like it to work event if the header looks like that :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetEmployeesTest2]
```

I would like to get : `uspGetEmployeesTest2`

Is there any library to to this ?

Comment: You can use regex https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following regex `CREATE PROCEDURE (?:dbo|\[dbo\])\.\[*(\w+)\]*`

See example: https://www.myregextester.com/?r=7e17ea0b

Updated to handle the case described by @JimL:
You should be able to use the following regex `CREATE PROCEDURE (?:dbo\.|\[dbo\]\.)*\[*([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+)\]*`

See example: https://www.myregextester.com/?r=c4a81cb3

With the above solution you may also want to `.Trim()` to remove leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is a valid SQL Procedure name: [My Procedure]

This may help some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151800/regular-expression-for-validating-sql-server-table-name